# How to send asynchronous HTTP requests from Django and wait for results in python2.7?

Tags: django, python-2.7, asynchronous, celery, tornado

I have several API's as sources of data, for example - blog posts. What I'm trying to achieve is to send requests to this API's in parallel from Django view and get results. No need to store results in db, I need to pass them to my view response. My project is written on python 2.7, so I can't use asyncio. I'm looking for advice on the best practice to solve it (celery, tornado, something else?) with examples of how to achieve that cause I'm only starting my way in async. Thanks.

Comment: Considering python 2.7 support ends in ~11 months, have you considered updating the project to use python 3?

Comment: I would love to, but I wouldn't ask this question if it would be possible for now.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found a solution using concurrent.futures ThreadPoolExecutor from [futures lib](https://pypi.org/project/futures/).

```
import concurrent.futures
import urllib.request

URLS = ['http://www.foxnews.com/',
        'http://www.cnn.com/',
        'http://europe.wsj.com/',
        'http://www.bbc.co.uk/',
        'http://some-made-up-domain.com/']

# Retrieve a single page and report the URL and contents
def load_url(url, timeout):
    with urllib.request.urlopen(url, timeout=timeout) as conn:
        return conn.read()

# We can use a with statement to ensure threads are cleaned up promptly
with concurrent.futures.ThreadPoolExecutor(max_workers=5) as executor:
    # Start the load operations and mark each future with its URL
    future_to_url = {executor.submit(load_url, url, 60): url for url in URLS}
    for future in concurrent.futures.as_completed(future_to_url):
        url = future_to_url[future]
        try:
            data = future.result()
        except Exception as exc:
            print('%r generated an exception: %s' % (url, exc))
        else:
            print('%r page is %d bytes' % (url, len(data)))
```

You can also check out the [rest of the concurrent.futures doc](https://docs.python.org/3/library/concurrent.futures.html#threadpoolexecutor-example).

**Important!**
The ProcessPoolExecutor class has known (unfixable) problems on Python 2 and should not be relied on for mission critical work.

Answer (score 0):

A solution is use Celery and pass your request args to this, and in the front use AJAX.

Example:

```
def my_def (request):
    do_something_in_celery.delay()
    return Response(something)
```

To control if a task is finished in Celery, you can put the return of Celery in a variable:

```
task_run = do_something_in_celery.delay()
```

In task_run there is a property .id.
This .id you return to your front and use it to monitor the status of task.

And your function executed in Celery must have de decorator @task

```
@task
do_something_in_celery(*args, **kwargs):
```

You will a need to control the tasks, like a Redis or RabbitMQ.

Look this URLs:

http://masnun.com/2014/08/02/django-celery-easy-async-task-processing.html

https://buildwithdjango.com/blog/post/celery-progress-bars/

http://docs.celeryproject.org/en/latest/index.html

Comment: Paulo, thanks for sharing. But the main goal is to avoid an additional AJAX request. Any ideas?

Comment: No, I don't know how do it without AJAX. Sorry !